# new class using author blocks

Tags: document-classes, authblk

I have created a simple .cls file in this example. I want to use `authblk` using the `blocks` mode.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2019/10/18 Test class]

\LoadClass[onecolumn]{article}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage[blocks]{authblk}
\setlength{\affilsep}{0em}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vskip-36pt%
  {\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@title}\par}%
  \vskip10pt
  {\raggedleft\sffamily \@author\par}
  \vskip18pt%
}
```

Then here goes the simple .tex file that uses the class above.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{testclass}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{author1}
\author{author2}
\affil{affil1}
\author{author3}
\author{author4}
\affil{affil2}
\title{Test Author Block}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

When there is more than one author I get the following error:

```
! Misplaced \crcr. \endtabular ->\crcr 
                    \egroup \egroup $\egroup  l.14 \maketitle
```

When using affiliation in footnote style it does compile with no errors.

```
\author[1]{author1}
\author[2]{author2}
\affil[1,2]{affil1}
\author[3]{author3}
\author[4]{author4}
\affil[3,4]{affil2}
```

What went wrong with the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer comes most likely too late, but it may be useful for someone ending up here... like me. I scratched my head for hours with this exact same problem.

I finally found the solution in the documentation of `authblk`. Well, actually in the package implementation details in `authblk.dtx` that are not included in `authblk.pdf` by default (at least in TeX Live). From the section **Basic Idea**:

> Clearly, the definition of `\and` must be compatible with the environment in which `\@author` is output.

By default, `\and` expects to be used inside a `tabular` environment. Redefining `\and` to your liking solves the issue. For example, add the following to your class definition:

```
\renewcommand{\and}{\vskip10pt}
```

An the complete test class definition will be:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2019/10/18 Test class]

\LoadClass[onecolumn]{article}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage[blocks]{authblk}
\setlength{\affilsep}{0em}
\renewcommand{\and}{\vskip10pt} % <- new line

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vskip-36pt%
  {\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@title}\par}%
  \vskip10pt
  {\raggedleft\sffamily \@author\par}
  \vskip18pt%
}
```

Compiling your example then yields the following without any error.

[image]